# IOS 7 determine if "Show in Notification Center" is disabled

Tags: ios, ios7, notifications

i am using the following code to determine whether alert notifications are enabled by the user

```
UIRemoteNotificationType notificationType =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];

if (!(notificationType & UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert))
{

}
```

When i set

> Settings -> Notifications -> Appname -> "Show in Notification
>   Center" to YES

and select Alert type to alerts i get UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert for notificationType

When i set

> Settings -> Notifications -> Appname -> "Show in Notification
>   Center" to NO

Still i get UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert for notificationType. Is there a way to determine whether

> "Show in Notification Center"

is set to NO ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer - this cannot be done programmatically.

You can call this:

```
UIRemoteNotificationType types = [UIApplicationsharedApplication].enabledRemoteNotificationTypes;
```

Which gives following enum in your `UIRemoteNotificationType`:

```
typedef enum 
{    
  UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone    = 0,   
  UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge   = 1 << 0,   
  UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound   = 1 << 1,   
  UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert   = 1 << 2,   
  UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability = 1 << 3 
}
```

So you could know the type of notification enabled by user but would not know if the user has enabled or disabled notification center for your app.

Comment: how about iOS10? @Abhinav